# Riemann Integrability of a Piecewise Function

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

> Let
>   $$f(x)=
>     \begin{cases}
>     0 & \left( x\in \Bbb Q^{\mathrm C} \right)\\
>     \cfrac{1}{p} & \left( x=\cfrac{q}{p},\; p, q\in \Bbb N,\; \gcd(p, q)=1 \right)\\
>     \end{cases}
> $$
>   Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

Since there is always an irrational number in every interval of every partition $P=\{x_0 ,\; \cdots,\; x_n \}$, 
$$
L(P,f)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}0 \cdot \Delta x_i =0
$$
and $\sup L(P,f)=0$.

I assumed that since $f$ is Riemann integrable, then $\inf U(P,f)$ must be $0$ as well. Thus
$$
U(P,f)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\cfrac{1}{p_i} \cdot \Delta x_i =0
$$
where $p_i \in \Bbb N$, since $p_i \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

But I can't seem to prove it. Am I missing something, or is my assumption just wrong?

**Edit:**

Similar to [Is Thomae's function Riemann integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17275/is-thomaes-function-riemann-integrable) except the definition of Riemann integrability I'm using is:

Let $U(P,f)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}M_i \Delta x_i$, $L(P,f)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i \Delta x_i$ where $M_i =\sup f(x)$, $m_i =\inf f(x)$ for $x \in \left[ x_{i-1} , x_i \right]$. $f$ is Riemann integrable if $\inf U(P,f) = \sup L(P,f)$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Thomae's function Riemann integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17275/is-thomaes-function-riemann-integrable)

Comment: Which is your definition of the Riemann integrability, and which is the question exactly?!